# How to show dialog on the below of current selected editText

Tags: android

I would like to show dialog on the below of selected editText. I have a list of edittext. When I click one of those edit text, the dialog will be shown below of this edit text. I would like to try in the picture. Is that possible in android?

[I would like to try like this. I am sorry for my raw picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbS45.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction) and [NewQuickAction3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D) developed by lorensiuswlt. This will display PopOver dialog at position of click event. Try this, may help you.

Comment: I got problem loading page. :(

Comment: is there another url for it? I cannot see it. I got problem loading page.

Comment: I have used it my dear friend. I am not getting any error before. You are doing some mistake otherwise it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for this.  Use `showAsDropDown` or  `showAtLocation` like

```
 popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView, 50, -30);
```

See [Example of using PopupWindow](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

Answer (score 0):

After creating your dialog, get a LayoutParams object that you can use to set the x and y coordinates.  This works on any flavor of Android.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog myDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
layoutParams.x = 50;
layoutParams.y = 200;

myDialog.show();
```